# Should I put an index on a MySQL table that is frequently getting new rows

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm creating a table that will track certain keywords used when accessing a website. The table, for now, will be very simple:

```
id (INT, 11, unsigned, primary key, auto_inc)
keyword (VARCHAR, 32)
hits (INT, 10, unsigned)
```

Every time a user hits the site we will extract a series of keyword from their HTTP_REFERER and then count these in the table. If the keyword already exists in the table then we `hits++`, if not then we insert a new row with `hits=1`.

All very simple, the question is, should I make `keyword` an index on the table? From what I've read making a column an index that is constantly getting new rows added isn't going to help performance as the `INSERTS` become much slower. There will inevitably be a lot of `INSERTS`, so will the performance gain found by the quicker updates be outweighed by slowing down the inserts? If this table ends up being maybe ~100k rows, would an index even be beneficial? We'd be averaging about 4 queries per minute, so the load won't be high at all.

This question is very hypothetical but it's not easy to load test this without putting it under live load, which I don't want to do blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  In fact, you want a `unique` index:

```
create unique index keywords_keyword on keywords(keyword);
```

The reason you want this is so you can use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  The `insert` code looks like:

```
insert into keywords(keyword, hits)
    select YOURKEYWORD, 0
    on duplicate key update hits = hits + 1;
```

The overhead of adding the index may not even make the inserts longer.  With the index, MySQL can readily determine whether a keyword already exists in the table.  Without the index, it has to do a full table scan.  The full table scan probably takes more time than maintaining the index.

EDIT:

If you have multiple keywords, you can construct a query like this:

```
insert into keywords(keyword, hits)
    select YOURKEYWORD1 as keyword, 0 as hits union all
    select YOURKEYWORD2 as keyword, 0 as hits union all
    select YOURKEYWORD3 as keyword, 0 as hits
    on duplicate key update hits = hits + 1;
```

Comment: I was literally just reading about 'on duplicate key' as a means for testing the insert, thank you. If I have an array of these keywords, is there any way to concatenate this query to perform tests on multiple keywords in one hit? I don't want to have to `foreach()` query the DB. (disclaimer: I suck at SQL).